# lodash - group and populate arrays

Tags: lodash

Using lodash, how could I group the names of people that have the same birthdates as seen below?

I wrote this out using nested for loops but was thinking there would be a more elegant way of doing this in lodash. I haven't used it much and trying to figure out which function to use.

```
[
    { "birthdate": "1993", "name": "Ben" },
    { "birthdate": "1994", "name": "John" },
    { "birthdate": "1995", "name": "Larry" },
    { "birthdate": "1995", "name": "Nicole" },
    { "birthdate": "1996", "name": "Jane" },
    { "birthdate": "1996", "name": "Janet" },
    { "birthdate": "1996", "name": "Dora" },
]
```

to

```
[
    { "birthdate": "1993", "names": [ "Ben" ] }, 
    { "birthdate": "1994", "names": [ "John"] },
    { "birthdate": "1995", "names": [ "Larry", "Nicole" ] }, 
    { "birthdate": "1996", "names": [ "Jane", "Janet", "Dora" ] }        
]
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use [groupBy()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#groupBy) to group each item in the collection by `birthdate`. After grouping the items, you can use [map()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#map) to iterate each groups and form them into a new format that includes a `birthdate` and `names`. To acquire an array of names from the grouped items, you can use the [map()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#map) function again to return all the `name` values.

```
var result = _(source)
    .groupBy('birthdate')
    .map(function(items, bdate) {
      return {
        birthdate: bdate,
        names: _.map(items, 'name')
      };
    }).value();
```

```js
var source = [
    { "birthdate": "1993", "name": "Ben" },
    { "birthdate": "1994", "name": "John" },
    { "birthdate": "1995", "name": "Larry" },
    { "birthdate": "1995", "name": "Nicole" },
    { "birthdate": "1996", "name": "Jane" },
    { "birthdate": "1996", "name": "Janet" },
    { "birthdate": "1996", "name": "Dora" },
];
  
var result = _(source)
    .groupBy('birthdate')
    .map(function(items, bdate) {
      return {
        birthdate: bdate,
        names: _.map(items, 'name')
      };
    }).value();

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>';
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: @ballar Thanks It worked for me but Is there any way to group elements by date only where in the array of objects we have a dateTime property... refer : (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48562519/how-to-group-elements-using-lodash-group-by-angular-2-4)

Answer (score 3):

You can chain groupBy and map to achieve this.

```
_.chain(yourArray)
.groupBy('birthdate')
.toPairs()
.map(s=>{
return _.zipObject(['birthdate','names'],s)
})
.map(s=>{
s.names=_.map(s.names,x=>x.name);
return s;
})
.value()
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `reduce()` and `find()`

```js
   let arr = [{
 "birthdate": "1993",
 "name": "Ben"
},
{
 "birthdate": "1994",
 "name": "John"
},
{
 "birthdate": "1995",
 "name": "Larry"
},
{
 "birthdate": "1995",
 "name": "Nicole"
},
{
 "birthdate": "1996",
 "name": "Jane"
},
{
 "birthdate": "1996",
 "name": "Janet"
},
{
 "birthdate": "1996",
 "name": "Dora"
},
];

const res = arr.reduce((ac, a) => {
let temp = ac.find(x => x.birthdate === a.birthdate);
if (!temp) ac.push({ ...a,
 name: [a.name]
})
else temp.name.push(a.name)
return ac;
}, [])
console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

An simple and customizable pure javascript function to return an array of objects grouped by the attribute needed in the object

```
export const groupArrayBy = (arr, groupBy) => {

    let newArr = []
    arr.map((item) => {
        if(item[groupBy]) {
            let finded = newArr.filter((newItem) => newItem[groupBy] === item[groupBy])
            if(finded.length > 0) {
                finded[0].products.push(item)
            } else {
                newArr.push({category: item[groupBy], products: [item]})
            }
        }
    })

    return newArr
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lodash shortand

```js
var data=[
    { "birthdate": "1993", "name": "Ben" },
    { "birthdate": "1994", "name": "John" },
    { "birthdate": "1995", "name": "Larry" },
    { "birthdate": "1995", "name": "Nicole" },
    { "birthdate": "1996", "name": "Jane" },
    { "birthdate": "1996", "name": "Janet" },
    { "birthdate": "1996", "name": "Dora" },
];


var list= _(data)
    .groupBy('birthdate')
    .map((items, birthdate)=> ({birthdate: birthdate,names: _.map(items, 'name')
      })).value();
      
      console.log(list)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```