# Multi level grouping and populate arrays with using lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am looking the following example [lodash - group and populate arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42081375/lodash-group-and-populate-arrays).

However I need to group by multi times like following example. What should I do? Thanks

```
    [
      { birthdate: "1993", day: "12", category: "a", name: "Ben" },
      { birthdate: "1993", day: "13", category: "a", name: "John" },
      { birthdate: "1993", day: "14", category: "b", name: "Larry" },
      { birthdate: "1994", day: "15", category: "", name: "Nicole" },        
    ];
```

to

```
[
  {
    birthdate: "1993",
    birthdateDetail: [
      {
        category: "a",
        categoryDetail: [
          { day: "12", name: "Ben" },
          { day: "13", name: "John" },
        ],
      },
      {
        category: "b",
        categoryDetail: [{ day: "14", name: "Larry" }],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    birthdate: "1994",
    birthdateDetail: [{ category: "", day: "15", name: "Nicole" }],
  },
];
```

Comment: It looks like the structure of the data changes depending on if there are multiple items with the same category/detail. Is that on purpose? Life will be easier in general if your data has a consistent structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could groups with an abstract approach for nested grouping by taking an object which keeps the keys for each level as well as the wanted result structure.

This approach works for arbitrary nesting.

```js
const
    data = [{ birthdate: "1993", day: "12", category: "a", name: "Ben" }, { birthdate: "1993", day: "13", category: "a", name: "John" }, { birthdate: "1993", day: "14", category: "b", name: "Larry" }, { birthdate: "1994", day: "15", category: "", name: "Nicole" }],
    groups = ['birthdate', 'category'],
    getEmpty = () => ({ _: [] }),
    result = data
      .reduce((q, o) => {
          groups
              .reduce((r, k) => {
                  const v = o[k];
                  if (!v) return r;
                  if (!r[v]) r._.push({ [k]: v, [k + 'Detail']: (r[v] = getEmpty())._ });
                  return r[v];
              }, q)
              ._
              .push(o);
          return q;
      }, getEmpty())
      ._;

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're in the right direction: using `_.groupBy` will help you to group your data, but since you need two levels of nesting, you will need to run it twice:

1. The top level is to group by `birthdate`
2. The second level is to group by `category`

Since [`_.groupBy` returns an object](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#groupBy), we will need to use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to transform the key-value pair into an array of objects that fit the shape you have intended.

At the second level, we will need to do a final iteration to ensure that we remove the `category` and `birthday` keys from the nested data.

See proof-of-concept below:

```js
const data = [
  { birthdate: "1993", day: "12", category: "a", name: "Ben" },
  { birthdate: "1993", day: "13", category: "a", name: "John" },
  { birthdate: "1993", day: "14", category: "b", name: "Larry" },
  { birthdate: "1994", day: "15", category: "", name: "Nicole" },        
];

// Top level: group by birthdate
const dataByBirthdate = _.groupBy(data, d => d.birthdate);

// Convert object into array of objects
const transformedData = Object.entries(dataByBirthdate).map(entry => {
  const [birthdate, value] = entry;

  // Second level: group by category
  const birthdatedetailByCategory = _.groupBy(value, d => d.category);
  const birthdatedetail = Object.entries(birthdatedetailByCategory).map(entry => {
    const [category, value] = entry;
    
    // Step through all entries to ensure we remove keys of your selection
    const categorydetail = value.map(d => {
      delete d.birthdate;
      delete d.category;
      return d;
    });
    
    return { category, categorydetail };
  });
  
  return { birthdate, birthdatedetail };
});

console.log(transformedData);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is function to group array with lodash:

```
const formatedResponse = _(arr)
  .groupBy("birthdate")
  .map((items, birthdate) => {
    const birthdateDetails = _(items)
      .groupBy("category")
      .map((items, category) => {
        return {
          category,
          categoryDetails: items.map(({ day, name }) => ({ day, name }))
        };
      })
      .value();

    return {
      birthdate,
      birthdateDetails
    };
  })
  .value();
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this

```js
const data = [
  { birthdate: "1993", day: "12", category: "a", name: "Ben" },
  { birthdate: "1993", day: "13", category: "a", name: "John" },
  { birthdate: "1993", day: "14", category: "b", name: "Larry" },
  { birthdate: "1994", day: "15", category: "", name: "Nicole" },        
];


const group = (data) => {
  return _(data)
    .groupBy('birthdate')
    .map((birthdateItems, birthdate) => ({
        birthdate,
        birthdateDetail: _(birthdateItems)
          .groupBy('category')
          .map((catgoryItems, category) => ({
              category,
              categoryDetail: _(catgoryItems)
                  .map(item => _.omit(item, ['birthdate', 'category']))
                  .value()
          }))
          .value()
    }))
    .value();
}

console.log(group(data));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```